# Bootstrap fixed width images in 2 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to do something like this ? http://morenheit-vesna.tumblr.com/

Say I have 5 images with same widths but different heights. How can I achieve this ?

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/77855c8b4bb6accb5713c746c730e94c/tumblr_o8gwskDNhK1t0yoveo1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/1a0b08e263025da71c9312014e7aa791/tumblr_o5xcdidD051tvh80lo1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/578a06593a0efc258e62fd5546d096f7/tumblr_o5gdhuOJcx1rx771wo1_500.png">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/7701c0870eb08dda60cd7490edf472ed/tumblr_mrs5f7cI9z1rnb624o1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/bac0f0e6a248059a2cd61d6f43e34689/tumblr_ngspo2vD3V1t0yoveo1_500.jpg">
</div>
```

Now they are all in one column with same width in y-axis without paddings

Answer (score 0):

I think, I did :D

```
<div id="content">
<div class = "col-md-6 text-center">
    <img src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/77855c8b4bb6accb5713c746c730e94c/tumblr_o8gwskDNhK1t0yoveo1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/1a0b08e263025da71c9312014e7aa791/tumblr_o5xcdidD051tvh80lo1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/578a06593a0efc258e62fd5546d096f7/tumblr_o5gdhuOJcx1rx771wo1_500.png">
</div>
<div class = "col-md-6 text-center">
    <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/7701c0870eb08dda60cd7490edf472ed/tumblr_mrs5f7cI9z1rnb624o1_500.jpg">
    <img src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/bac0f0e6a248059a2cd61d6f43e34689/tumblr_ngspo2vD3V1t0yoveo1_500.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. One would be to create a table, say, with 5 columns, and within each table cell deploy all the pictures you want for each cell (taking care of margins of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can even try `float` option and then using `margin` to align them properly as below,

```
#content > img{
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: but bootstrap is responsive .s

Comment: Yes it is, but to adjust it's in-between spacing you could try margin from above, (i.e.) for image bottom or top or left or right margin.